# Сумма ряда Фибоначчи

Tags: c, числа-фибоначчи

Не используя рекурсию и циклы, найти сумму чисел ряда Фибоначчи от 1 до n.

Comment: Назовите источник задачи.

Comment: А вы уверены, что это возможно? Это же не какая-то арифметическая прогрессия, чтобы одним ударом посчитать.. попробуйте на математике спросить.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Сумма элементов до *n* — это просто *F(n + 2) - 1*. То есть, нужно найти число Фибоначчи через одно от *n*-ого и вычесть единицу.

Как найти нужно число Фибоначчи Вам [уже написал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/73573/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8#73578) Станислав.

Answer (score 2):

Это делается очень просто с помощью [формулы Бине](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8#.D0.A4.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D1.83.D0.BB.D0.B0_.D0.91.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B5), которая в явном виде выражает значение числа в зависимости от его порядкового номера в ряду Фибоначчи.

Answer (score 2):

[Числа Фибоначчи](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8)

Первое же тождество - как раз то, что вам нужно.
Формула для n-ого члена написана повыше.

Comment: Так а что толку от n-го элемента? Нужна сумма.